# Orders in Streams in java

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list and a treeSet of Integers when I call unordered and parallel methods on streams of two collections I get different results the first gets an ordered result but the second gets an unordered result.

```java
List<Integer> list = List.of(-9, -5, -4, -2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 13, 16, 29, 23, 34, 57, 102, 230);

Object[] collect = list.stream().unordered().parallel().limit(3).toArray();
for (Object s : collect) {
    System.out.println((Integer) s);
}

System.out.println();

Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(list);
Object[] collect2 = set.stream().unordered().parallel().limit(3).toArray();
for (Object s : collect2) {
    System.out.println((Integer) s);
}
```

On the other hand, I don't understand why if I don't call the limit in the second stream I always get an ordered list

```java
Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(list);
Object[] collect2 = set.stream().unordered().parallel().limit(3).toArray();
for (Object s : collect2) {
    System.out.println((Integer) s);
}

Set<Integer> set3 = new TreeSet<>(list);
Object[] collect3 = set3.stream().unordered().parallel().toArray();
for (Object s : collect2) {
    System.out.println((Integer) s);
}
```

Comment: Note `unordered` doesn't _require_ the stream to unorder itself, it simply removes the constraint that it _must be_ ordered. In other words, the collector won't align the order of the stream as a postfix operation. For your test case, I would claim a very small sample size. Run it with varying limits, do a million runs of each limit and ensure the results are consistent. Then question why they are (perhaps a cache hit? system config?), if they are.

Comment: TreeSet is ordered, so streaming on all elements and getting them in order is not surprising, even when the stream itself is unordered: after all, `unordered` only means that the order of the streamed items is not relevant, not that the stream will go out of its way to shuffle the elements if it can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

> The unordered() operation doesn't do any actions to explicitly unorder the stream. What it does is that it removes the constraint on the stream that it must remain ordered, thereby allowing subsequent operations to use optimizations that don't have to take ordering into consideration.

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21350234/20993511

If you want to get your stream randomized or shuffled then you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36391959/20993511).